# How do I find the least multiple of N in a list of numbers using Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to find the least multiple of N in a list of numbers.

```
leastMultiple/2
leastMultipleOfThree/2, 
arg1= list of numbers,arg2= X (X is what we want to find, the least multiple of 3 in a list of numbers).
```

For example, find the least multiple of 3 in [7,9,15,22]. I have been staring at this for quite some time, and I'm not entirely sure where to begin. If you can simply help me wrap my head *around* the problem a bit, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: And what have you tried? and why does it fail?

Comment: I need to learn how to do it so i can explain it to my brother. I realy need the help.

Comment: Example: Find the least multiple of 3 in a list [7,9,15,22]                      . ?-( [7,9,15,22], X) and i get X=9

Comment: @user3512239 Could you include a piece of code that you have created? The fact that you are explaining things to your brother does not give us a hunch as to where your misunderstand resides.

Comment: @WouterBeek He has to make a piece of code like this: leastMultipleOfThree/2, arg1= list of numbers,arg2= X (X is what we want to find, the least multiple of 3 in a list of numbers. Example, find the least multiple of 3 in [7,9,15,22].

Comment: Nice, a little brother that's learning Prolog... I never seen this before. Prolog audience is growing...

Comment: Could somone give me a solution the the problem ?

Comment: @sbi Over email he explained his older brother opened this question for him on SO. I gave him a spiel about how SO is supposed to be used...

Answer (score 6):

An earlier version of my answer was confused by the use of the word "least multiple." You want to find the multiples in the list, and retrieve the smallest. I understand now.

First we must detect a multiple of N. We can do this by dividing and looking at the remainder using the modulo operator, like this:

```
?- X is 7 mod 3.
X = 1.

?- X is 9 mod 3.
X = 0.
```

I will define a convenience method for this, is_multiple_of:

```
% multiple_of(X, N) is true if X is a multiple of N
multiple_of(X, N) :- 0 is X mod N.
```

Now we can simply say:

```
?- multiple_of(7, 3).
false.

?- multiple_of(9, 3).
true.
```

Now there are two ways to proceed. The efficient approach, which could easily be made tail recursive for greater performance, would be to walk the list once with an accumulator to hold the current minimum value. A less code-intensive approach would be to just filter the list down to all multiples and sort it. Let's look at both approaches:

```
% less code: using setof/3
leastMultipleOfThree(List, Result) :-
    setof(X, (member(X, List), multiple_of(X, 3)), [Result|_]).
```

`setof/3` evaluates its second term as many times as possible, each time retrieving the variable in its first term for inclusion in the result, the third term. In order to make the list unique, `setof/3` sorts the result, so it happens that the smallest value will wind up in the first position. We're using `member(X, List), multiple_of(X, 3)` as a very simple generate-test pattern. So it's terse, but it doesn't read very well, and there are costs associated with building lists and sorting that mean it isn't optimal. But it is terse!

```
% more code: using an accumulator
leastMultipleOfThree(List, Result) :- leastMultipleOfThree(List, null, Result).

% helper
leastMultipleOfThree([], Result, Result) :- Result \= null.
leastMultipleOfThree([X|Xs], C, Result) :-
    multiple_of(X, 3) 
        -> (C = null -> leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, X, Result)
                      ; (Min is min(X, C), 
                         leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, Min, Result)))
         ; leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, C, Result).
```

This is quite a bit more code, because there are several cases to be considered. The first rule is the base case where the list is extinguished; I chose `null` arbitrarily to represent the case where we haven't yet seen a multiple of three. The test on the right side ensures that we fail if the list is empty and we never found a multiple of three.

The second rule actually handles three cases. Normally I would break these out into separate predicates, but there would be a lot of repetition. It would look something like this:

```
leastMultipleOfThree([X|Xs], null, Result) :-
  multiple_of(X, 3), 
  leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, X, Result).
leastMultipleOfThree([X|Xs], C, Result) :-
  multiple_of(X, 3),
  C \= null,
  Min is min(X, C),
  leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, Min, Result).
leastMultipleOfThree([X|Xs], C, Result) :-
  \+ multiple_of(X, 3),
  leastMultipleOfThree(Xs, C, Result).
```

This may or may not be more readable (I prefer it) but it certainly performs worse, because each of these rules creates a choice point that if/else conditional expressions within a rule do not. It would be tempting to use cuts to improve that, but you'll certainly wind up in a hellish labyrinth if you try it.

I hope it's fairly self-explanatory at this point. :)

Comment: instead of having to deal with `null`, perhaps it's better to change the interface predicate `leastMultipleOfThree/2` to explicitly handle the non-empty list case and thus let it fail in case the list is empty, to have the simpler and more uniform code in `leastMultipleOfThree/3`.